# Kendo Confirmation is undefined after clicking on "Cancel" button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-confirm

I saw similar questions but unfortunately did not find an answer I was looking for.

I have Kendo Confirmation dialog that I need to be displayed under a certain condition when clicking on an "Update" button:

```
<button class="k-button k-primary" id="btnSave" type="button"  @*name="action:Save"*@ onclick="CheckSplitCondition()">Update</button>

function CheckSplitCondition()
{
    var newResolvedAmount = $('#ResolvedAmount').val();

    var isSplit;
    var diff = @Model.Amount - newResolvedAmount;
    var msg = "Difference between Resolve Amount and Ticket Amount is:" + diff + ".\nThis Amount is going to be put in newly created ticket.\nPress 'OK' to proceed, press 'Cancel' otherwise.\n";

    var dispResult = $("#displayResults");
    if ((Math.abs(newResolvedAmount) <= Math.abs(@Model.Amount)) && newResolvedAmount != 0) {
        //$("#displayResults").css("display", "block");
        $("#displayResults").kendoConfirm({
            width: "400px",
            title: "Alert",
            closable: true,
            modal: true,
            content: 'Are you sure?',
            okText: "OK"
        }).data("kendoConfirm").result.done(function () { SaveData(); }).fail(function () { alert('2') });

    }
    else {
        SaveData();
    }
}
```

After clicking on "Cancel", confirmation box is not showing and I have `JavaScript error` telling

> "Unable to get property 'result' of undefined or null reference"

Not sure why that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo Confirm is based on Kendo Dialog, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog#methods-destroy) removes the HTML elements from the DOM when it is destroyed:

> destroy
>
> Destroys the dialog and its modal overlay, if necessary. Removes the widget HTML elements from the DOM.

This is why it only works the first time around, and you receive a null reference on the second pass because the `<div>` no longer exists. This behaviour is typical of Kendo widgets which have been destroyed.

The quickest solution would be to call the `kendo.confirm()` method, as in [this demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/predefined-dialogs). Unfortunately, that is a very simple helper method which only allows you to specify the message text as an argument.

Alternatively, you could use jQuery to create a new `<div>` each time, and then turn that into a Dialog like so (which retains the flexibility to completely customise the Dialog):

```
var confirmDialog = $('<div />').kendoConfirm({
    content: "Are you sure that you want to proceed?",
    title: "Custom Title"
}).data('kendoConfirm').open();

confirmDialog.result.then(function () {
    kendo.alert("You chose the Ok action.");
}, function () {
    kendo.alert("You chose to Cancel action.");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already figured it out and did exactly what you suggest here.

Comment: Can we change the title of kendo.confirm()?

Comment: Not by calling `kendo.confirm()` unfortunately, as you can only pass the message text as an argument. You would need to do it much as @gene has done above, but using a new `<div>` each time. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @genericuser answer updated to show how the confirm title can be changed.